# Iterate through a String while placing its values in a Dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, string, dataframe

I am trying to place all of a strings values, into a data frame where the rows*columns= the length of the string. So for i have

```
for i in range (len(string)):
    while(j<len(df)|z<len(df.columns)):
       df[j][z]=string[i]
df
```

But df returns with all values as NAN, ive tried using double nested for loops aswell to no affect, aswell an if else statement checking if the index doesnt go over out of bounds for the string. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can turn the string into an array of the appropriate size with something like

```
np.array(list(string)).reshape(len(df), -1)
```

Placing it in the DF should be simple after that, assuming it has a character dtype across all columns.

Comment: Im sorry i dont really understand this, do you mind explaining further?

Comment: Never mind i got it thanks youre a legend. Have a good one.