# Key Error after iterating a string through a data frame

Tags: python, dataframe, keyerror

Previously i employed this fix given to me [Iterate through a String while placing its values in a Dataframe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72823610/iterate-through-a-string-while-placing-its-values-in-a-dataframe/72823640#72823640) inorder to iterate a string through a dataframe, but after developing the loops python throws a Key Error to me with the number of columns attach, for example if the number of columns is 45 it will throw a Key Error: 45
Below is the code im using inorder to loop:

```
for i in range (rows):
    j=0
    while(j<columns-1):
        df[i][j]=converted_array[i][j]
        j=j+1

        
        
df
```

And this throws a keyerror to me.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Perhaps you should print out `columns` at the top of your while loop. Perhaps it's not what you think it is.

Comment: Python list indexes start at 0.  So if there are 45 columns, then the valid indexes are 0-44.  There is indeed no column 45.

Comment: When I employ the code that @rajah9 said it just prints the amount of columns till it throws the same Key Error. The error is being thrown when it tries to place the values inside the df